# Error: Optional(Alamofire.AFError.invalidURL(""))

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am just starting to code with Swift, and I came across this error while building an app using Alamofire

The error is :

> Error: Optional(Alamofire.AFError.invalidURL(""))

This is my code. Can someone help??

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


    let baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTC"

    let currencyArray = ["AUD", "BRL","CAD","CNY","EUR","GBP","HKD","IDR","ILS","INR","JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","RON","RUB","SEK","SGD","USD","ZAR"]

    let currencySymbolsArray = ["$", "R$", "$", "¥", "€", "£", "$", "Rp", "₪", "₹", "¥", "$", "kr", "$", "zł", "lei", "₽", "kr", "$", "$", "R"]

    var currencySymbol = ""

    var finalURL = ""


    //Pre-setup IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var bitcoinPriceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencyPicker: UIPickerView!

    // determine number of columns
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // determine number of rows
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return currencyArray.count
    }

    // fill in each row with title from array
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return currencyArray[row]
    }

    // Print something when you select a row
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print (currencyArray[row])

        finalURL = baseURL + currencyArray[row]
        print(finalURL)
        currencySymbol = currencyArray[row]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currencyPicker.delegate = self
        currencyPicker.dataSource = self

        getCurrencyData(url: finalURL)
    }


    //TODO: Place your 3 UIPickerView delegate methods here

//    //MARK: - Networking
//    /***************************************************************/
    func getCurrencyData(url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    print("Success! Got the currency data ")

                    let currencyJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    self.updateCurrencyData(json: currencyJSON)
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    self.bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "Connection issues"
                } 
            }
    }


//    //MARK: - JSON Parsing
//    /***************************************************************/

    func updateCurrencyData(json : JSON) {
        if let currencyResult = json["ask"].double  {
            bitcoinPriceLabel.text = " \(currencySymbol) +  \(currencyResult) "
        } else {
            bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "Currency unavailable"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `viewDidLoad()` you call `getCurrencyData`. Question: What's the value of `finalURL` in that case? Does it seems valid when you do `print(finalURL)`? If you copy/paste it in Safari.app or any other browser, does it works? Also is it exactly the same (no extra percent escapes % added ?)

Comment: Yes, the address works. These are two examples

Comment: CAD
https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCCAD
EUR
https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCEUR

Comment: both start with https: // (i did not appear when i copied/pasted for some reason). And no, no extra % as far as i can see

Comment: Let's clarify again: In `viewDidLoad()`, just before `getCurrencyData(url: finalURL)`, `finalURL` is `""`, no? That's why, no?

Comment: yes, that is why it blocked. Basically i called an empty url by calling my function in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `getCurrencyData` from your view controllers `viewDidLoad` method, while the value of `finalURL` is still its initial value, namely `""`, which is exactly what you see as the invalid URL in the error message.

You only need to make the network call once the user actually makes a selection using the picker.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    currencySymbol = currencySymbolsArray[row]
    getCurrencyData(url: baseURL + currencyArray[row])
}
```

There's also no need for the `finalURL` variable, since you can directly input the data you stored in `finalURL` to the `getCurrencyData` function.

Unrelated to the error, but you were also setting wrong data to `currencySymbol`, since you were assigning data to it from the `currencyArray` rather than the `currencySymbolArray`.

Comment: 5 star s!! It makes sense, and IT WORKED!!